# c++ how to elegantly use c++17 parallel execution with for loop that counts an integer?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

I can do

```
std::vector<int> a;
a.reserve(1000);
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    a.push_back(i);
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int i) {
  ... do something based on i ...
});
```

but is there a more elegant way of creating a parallelized version of for(int i=0; i<n; i++) that does not require me to first fill a vector with ascending ints?

Answer (score 12):

You could use `std::generate` to create a vector `{0, 1, ..., 999}`

```
std::vector<int> v(1000);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0] () mutable { return n++; });
```

There is an overload that accepts an `ExecutionPolicy` so you could modify the above to

```
std::vector<int> v(1000);
std::generate(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0] () mutable { return n++; });
```

Comment: that's already more elegant, thank you (though I doubt the compiler could parallelize that?)! but I wonder if it's possible to do without having to fill a vector in the first place? is there some iterator that generates the ints procedurally instead and that can be used with std::for_each ?

Comment: I think once C++20 is out you could use [ranges](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) to accomplish something like this.

Comment: boost::counting_range has existed for ages

Comment: Thrust has had [counting iterators](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1counting__iterator.html) forever. Unfortunately the fancy iterator concept didn't make it into the standard

Answer (score 9):

Although I can't suggest a way to avoid filling a vector, I can recommend using the [`std::iota()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) function as (perhaps) the most efficient/elegant way to fill it with incrementing integers:

```cpp
std::vector<int> a(1000);
std::iota(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0);
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int i) {
  // ... do something based on i ...
});
```

The complexity of `std::iota` is exactly `last - first` *increments* and assignments, whereas the `std::generate` function has a complexity of `last - first` *invocations of `g()`* and assignments. Even if a decent compiler were to inline a simple increment lambda function for `g`, the `iota` syntax is considerably simpler, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

VisualC++ provides a rich parallel programming enviromnent, concurrency runtime [ConCRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/parallel-programming-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019).
You can use OpenMP, which is open standard but also available in ConCRT. As described on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) it is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), following code is supposed to create 1000 threads:

```cpp
#include <omp.h>
...
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int s = 0; s < 1000; s++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        ... do something parallel based on i ...
}
```

The #pragma omp directives are ignored if compiler option /openmp is not specified.
In fact I don't understand the role of your vector, so I omitted it. Also I don't understand the reasoning behind the replacing of the standard **for** with any **for_each** and work with saved indexes, since **for** loop does it pretty well. 
Or you can use Microsoft specific library PPL. Following code also creates 1000 threads, generating indexes from 0 to 999 inclusive and passing to parallel routine as **s** variable:

```cpp
#include <ppl.h>
...
using namespace concurrency;
parallel_for(0, 1000, [&](int s)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
      ... do something parallel based on i ...
});
```

For heavy parallel computations there is also AMP available in concurrency runtime. AMP does the parallel routines on GPU instead of CPU.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways to do it *without* pre-populating a vector just to store a sequence of integers.

1. You *can* do it with [`Boost.counting_range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html) (or directly using [`Boost.counting_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) as you prefer) ... although good luck finding out how from reading the documentation.

   ```
    auto range = boost::counting_range<int>(0,1000);
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,
                  range.begin(),
                  range.end(),
                  [&](int i) {
                      //  ... do something based on i ...
                  });
   ```
2. If you don't want to include Boost, we can write a simple version directly.

   With no apology for munging `iota` and `iterator` together instead of coming up with a decent name, the below will let you write something similar to the Boost version above:

   ```
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,
                  ioterable<int>(0),
                  ioterable<int>(1000),
                  [&](int i) {
                    //  ... do something based on i ...
                  }
    );
   ```

   You can see how much boilerplate you save by using Boost for this:

   ```
    template <typename NumericType>
    struct ioterable
    {
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = NumericType;
        using difference_type = NumericType;
        using pointer = std::add_pointer_t<NumericType>;
        using reference = NumericType;

        explicit ioterable(NumericType n) : val_(n) {}

        ioterable() = default;
        ioterable(ioterable&&) = default;
        ioterable(ioterable const&) = default;
        ioterable& operator=(ioterable&&) = default;
        ioterable& operator=(ioterable const&) = default;

        ioterable& operator++() { ++val_; return *this; }
        ioterable operator++(int) { ioterable tmp(*this); ++val_; return tmp; }
        bool operator==(ioterable const& other) const { return val_ == other.val_; }
        bool operator!=(ioterable const& other) const { return val_ != other.val_; }

        value_type operator*() const { return val_; }

    private:
        NumericType val_{ std::numeric_limits<NumericType>::max() };
    };
   ```
3. For posterity, and in case you can use C++20 in the future, [`std::ranges::iota_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) will preferable where available.

Comment: At least in the sequential case Boosts counting_iterator is certainly the right tool. If it doesn't work with parallel execution I would suggest the Thrust library with it's OMP or TBB backend. It provides parallel implementations of STL algorithms as well as smart iterators like the counting_iterator.

Comment: Actually, maybe that _is_ sufficient. The doc doesn't show the `operator==` you need to use it for the primary [begin,end) range, but maybe it's there and just not mentioned.

Comment: As far as I remember the docs don't go into much depth (and don't contain a quick reference?), so one may be better off just looking at the source. But using that iterator without ```operator==`` would be quite a niche thing, right?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, but I haven't used it myself, it's not clearly documented and honestly I can't quickly make it out from a glance at the code. Oh, I think it's generated by macro in a friend class ... yuck