# Using more power from CPU

Tags: c++, c

Imagin of this code:

```
#define ArraySize 10000
unsigned char ucA[ArraySize];
unsigned int counter;
for(counter=0;counter<ArraySize;counter++)
    ucA[counter]=some_Function();
}
```

In my computer it take about 24 to about 25 (sometimes less sometimes more) percentage of CPU time/power, lets assume 1/4 of CPU.

How can I take more of my CPU capability such as 2/4 or 3/4?

If it is necessary to say, I am using Windows 10 64-bit OS; x64 based processor
4 gig RAM, Intel Core i3, Embarcadero C++Builder

:-) Thx

Comment: Let's say your CPU has 4 physical cores, it can run 4 threads truly parallel. If you program uses only one thread it can occupy only one core (25% of the cpu). The keyword is multithreading. (But I'm not entirely sure if that's what you mean)

Comment: Generally you can't "use more power from CPU". What you might be able to do is to *optimize* your code, or considering the example you show *parallelize* it using e.g. threads.

Comment: You could just hit it with the OpenMP hammer.

Answer (score 5):

Provided that `some_Function()` does not spawn any threads, your program is limited to a single thread of execution.

What you should do is distribute the work over more of your cores.  Do it by hand (using `std::async` for instance), or use a specialized library (intel's [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/parallel_for.html), for instance).

Oh- and use the 'new' execution policy for the stl algorithms, like in [c++ how to elegantly use c++17 parallel execution with for loop that counts an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340193/c-how-to-elegantly-use-c17-parallel-execution-with-for-loop-that-counts-an-i).

And keep Ahmdal's law in mind :).

Comment: Sorry but I did not get your meaning about Ahmad's law!

Comment: @PedramHaghighy Typo: Amdahls law -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law

Comment: You can make all your CPU's go hot, but might not gain no extra speed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to utilize all the cores you can call the `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` function to get the number of available threads. The easiest way to spawn multiple threads is to use `std::async` and `std::future`.

I commented out the array, because it can't be big enough as it is allocated on stack. I made ArraySize big enough for the program to give noticeable impact on the CPU.

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>

#define ArraySize 1000000000

int main()
{
    auto task = [] () {
        //unsigned char ucA[ArraySize];
        for(std::size_t counter=0;counter<ArraySize;counter++) {
            //ucA[counter]=some_Function();
        }
    };

    // get thread count
    const auto thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    // declare a vector of tasks
    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;
    tasks.reserve(thread_count);

    // create tasks and put them into the vector
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) {
        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, task));
    }
    
    // wait for all the tasks to complete
    for (auto &t : tasks) {
       t.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```