# Function with loop as parameter

Tags: c++

I have the following two function bodies, let `A` be a set of instructions, and let `B(i,A)` be another set of instructions that depends on `A` (for example a variable that is defined in `A` is used in `B`) and `i`:

```
//do A
for(auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  //do B(i, A)
}
```

and

```
//do A
for(auto i : someNumbers) {
  //do B(i, A)
}
```

Is there some way of expressing this in a single function dependant on the loop without losing performance? One could of course state the function in terms of a vector, but then one has to create that vector in the first case.

The code duplication is the repetition of `A` and `B(i,A)`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The question is unclear for me and it could help understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't think we need an MRE for a clear _how to accomplish X_ question.

Comment: The problem is that a minimal example which makes sense in itself would contain a lot of noise which is not relevant for the problem.

Comment: The point of your question seems to focus on the looping setup. Couldn't you remove the `//do A` comment and change `//do B(i, A)` to either `// Do stuff` or `foo(i); // some function`? It's should go for granted that you might have more parameters to `foo` in yoir real setup. 
*What I find confusing about your example is figuring out what `A` is supposed to represent, in a way that makes sense in both places it appears. Abstracting `A` away would make your example more minimal, more complete, and less confusing.*

Comment: No, it is not really possible to remove ```//do A``` because then there would not be code duplication if you just have a function ```foo(i)```. The part before the loop is relevant here.

Comment: @Henk That's really confusing. I don't see code duplication in your question. I think you need to be more explicit with your example code. If `A` is supposed to be a function call, why is it commented out? If it's just several lines of code to execute, how can it be a parameter to `B`?

Comment: ```A``` is just a series of instrutions that could be anything. ```B``` is another set of instruction that somehow depends on the instructions on ```A```. Is that notation so unclear, what would you propose instead. Also I think that this question should be reopened because it describes exatly one problem and has a very good answer for that problem. If there is a better to way to state this abstract dependence, it should maybe be edited. I just do not get what is so unclear.

Comment: @Henk *"Is that notation so unclear,"* YES. Using functional notation for something that is not a function call is unclear. It might work in something a step more abstract than pseudo-code, but it is confusing when presented in an actual code block. *"what would you propose instead."* -- I think your point is that the code before the loop cannot be moved to a separate function (since it declares a variable)? Weak and ignored by the accepted answer, but I might demonstrate that as `/* common setup */ for(auto i : someNumbers) { /* Do stuff */ }`, and explain the relations in text, not in code.

Comment: @Henk It might also help to give entire functions, not just function bodies. Give some idea of how these functions would be called, how `someNumbers` is supplied to the function, and why `someNumbers` could not be supplied as some (static) container of the numbers from 0 to 99.

Comment: The ```do A``` can be easily added to the answer before the loop. Then it is equivalent and exactly what I asked for. I agree that I could have given explaining names for ```A``` and ```B```, but the formal definition in the edited version clarifies that.

Comment: Giving context for how these functions should be called narrows down the question and asks a different question. This would be an X-Y-Problem. This is a "How to accomplish X" question, not a "How to solve Y" question.

Comment: @Henk *"Giving context for how these functions should be called"* -- not "should", but "could". Not restricting, but giving context. (By the way, since you brought them up, a lack of context is commonly a feature of XY problems.)

Comment: @Henk *"The do A can be easily added to the answer before the loop."* -- This backs up my suggestion that there's no need to have "do A" in your question. (Admittedly, that suggestion was softened when you added text explaining what you intended `A` and `B` to represent.)

Comment: No, it actually does not because there would be other solutions where adding ```A``` is not possible. I do not want such a solution, so I have to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, with the constraint that the common function should be inlinable.

You can encode the loop condition in an iterator pair or, ideally, a range.

- [Range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) version, if supported in C++20 mode:

  ```c++
  template <typename Range>
  void looper(Range r) {
      for (auto i : r) {
          B(i, A);
      }
  }
  ```

  1. use [`std::ranges::iota_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) for to generate the numeric interval, like

     ```c++
     looper(std::ranges::iota_view{0, 100});
     ```
  2. use [`std::views::all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/all_view) to just loop over a whole container:

     ```c++
     looper(std::views::all(someNumbers));
     ```
- More manual iterator version if you don't have range support yet:

  ```c++
  template <typename Iter>
  void looper(Iter begin, Iter end) {
      for (auto iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
          B(*iter, A);
      }
  }
  ```

  The whole-container version is trivial, but the generator takes a little effort. I already wrote a suitable one elsewhere, so I'll just link it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63341946/212858), with a bonus Boost version as well.

Comment: Very nice! I do not have access to c++20 yet, but the boost version is a good replacement.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand. If you wish to send the whole loop in a loop, you can send a function pointer of lambda function like this:

```
#include<functional>
void B(std::function<void()> func)
{
    func();
}

int main(void)
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        B([&](){for (auto j = 0; j < 100; j++) { } });
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can just do nested loop I guess...

But I think I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed that. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Yea, It really was a rush writing. But now I have fixed it again.