# C++17 parallel execution policy and lambda copies

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

It has come to my notice that multiple lambda instances seem to be created when parallel execution policy is used. At least, the address of a variable captured by copy is different for each thread:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <map>
#include <thread>


struct MyData
{
    int data = 333;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(10000);    
    std::transform(std::execution::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [dat = MyData()](int x)
    {
        thread_local auto tl = ((std::cout << &dat << std::endl), dat); 
        return x * x;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Both MSVC 16.9.0 and GCC 9.3.0 print an individual address of `dat` for each thread:

```
0047F328
005EF6A0
0085F518
00BEF598
00AEF818
```

That said, if I change the lambda to capture some variable by reference, the behavior alters regardless of whether we actually use that variable:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(10000);
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::transform(std::execution::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [dat = MyData(),&mtx](int x)
    {
        thread_local auto tl = ((std::cout << &dat << std::endl), dat);     
        return x * x;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Now MSVC is not longer creating copies:

```
0018F7740018F7740018F774
0018F774

0018F774

0018F774
0018F774
0018F774
0018F774
0018F774
0018F774
```

Whereas in GCC the address is still unique for each thread:

```
0x7ffdc8147590
0x7ff1eb62eb30
0x7ff1eae2cb30
0x7ff1eb22db30
0x7ff1e322db30
0x7ff1ea229b30
0x7ff1eaa2bb30
0x7ff1ea62ab30
```

I am wondering whether this behavior is defined somewhere or it is completely implementation-specific.

I have seen a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340193/c-how-to-elegantly-use-c17-parallel-execution-with-for-loop-that-counts-an-i) where a captured variable was used for parallel counting. But considering what I have written above, I am not sure whether such kind of approach would be reliable.

Comment: Trying to figure out what the compiler is doing is usually not very useful, as it's allowed to do basically whatever it wants in most situations as long as it follows the as-if rule. The language guaratees that copies are copies, and references are references. Captured inside lambdas or not makes no difference.

Comment: @super Well, that was actually the point of the question: whether it is compiler-specific or defined by the standard. I thought, probably, there is a rule in the standard mandating that if certain conditions are met, lambdas (and captured variables) are instantiated for each thread separately. Then we could exploit it to perform thread-private initialization in those conditions, for example.

Comment: Lambdas are function objects. So there is nothing different in how a lambda is treated compared to any other class/struct. Hence you will not find any specific rule about that.

Comment: "**[algorithms.parallel.user]/1** Unless otherwise specified, function objects passed into parallel algorithms ... shall not directly or indirectly modify objects via their arguments, nor shall they **rely on the identity of the provided objects**." Emphasis mine. It's not immediately clear to me whether "provided objects" include `*this` reference to the function object itself.