# Auto vectorize a function on four variables applied to four vectors

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, execution

C++17 Parallel algorithms let's us choose execution policy when calling std transform as long as we are dealing with a function that takes in two arguments or less. In my case I have a function that takes in 4 arguments and I want the compiler to auto vectorize it (assuming the function is not too complex for it).

Is there a way to achieve this with std transform without creating additional vectors to store intermediate results? Can we have a custom iterator that outputs the value of the function?

I thought about using zip from ranges in c++23 but don't have access to c++ latest.

Comment: What are the function arguments for? Can you call it from a lambda (that takes two arguments)? What is the *underlying* problem you want to solve? Why do you think using `std::transform` is the best solution?

Comment: The function calculates survival probability of each path in a Monte Carlo simulation given the start value, end value, prob of surviving so far. Sorry just realised there are only three vectors. I am under the opinion std transform will auto vectorize given par_unseq execution policy. Hence want to use it. Trying to avoid getting into Open MP or writing simd c++ or assembly.

Comment: You can always put your arguments in a struct and use a lambda to unpack them for the function call. Or, if you have vectors full of values, use `std::iota()` and the index in the lambda.

Comment: Hi @ypnos, I don't want extra storage of order n. Struct will duplicate storage of the four vectors

Comment: See my edit, or even use `std::ranges::iota_view` so everything stays virtual. This can also be an inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340193/c-how-to-elegantly-use-c17-parallel-execution-with-for-loop-that-counts-an-i

Comment: Thanks @ypnos. Let me try try this out. Hopefully compiler auto vectorizes it.